# how to force a tun/tap interface into RUNNING state

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I create a tun interface, bring it up and assign an ip addr to it using

```
sudo openvpn --mktun --dev tun2
sudo ip link set dev tun2 up
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev tun2
```

The interface is created but not in the RUNNING state and no packet shows up at the interface (capturing via tshark).
Given than I've already upped the interface (seemingly with no success), How can I force "tun2" into RUNNING state (my OS= ubuntu14.04).

ifconfig output shown below

```
tun2      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr   00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:10.0.0.1  P-t-P:10.0.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP POINTOPOINT NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the virtual interface will not be RUNNING until a software is attached to it.
As soon as my program (the simpletun.c example) attached to the interface, every thing became OK.